# Anuglar 2 Installing angular-rating-icons

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I am trying to install angular-rating-icons from here https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-rating-icons

I did the following:

```
npm install angular-rating-icons
```

I then copied the js file and css from the package into my assets folder and included the files in the index.html

I am just stuck on this part:

> Add the module to your main module's list of dependencies

```
angular.module('yourApp', [
    // ...
    'angular-rating-icons',
    // ...
]);
```

How do I add this module to my main module list of dependencies? I am fairly new to Angular 2. Which file has my list of dependencies?

Comment: this is not angular 2 actually is angularjs, fix you question.

Comment: did you try "npm install angular-rating-icons -- save"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Angular 2 but angular-rating-icons is an AngularJS library. Angular and AngularJS are two totally different technologies. This will never work!

Find an ngx package that does what you want and forget angular-rating-icons.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add angular-rating-icons to you `package.json` i.e main module list of dependencies you are referring to.

Use this -

> npm install angular-rating-icons -- save

Comment: I did that, but I get the same error `angular is not defined` when I include the js file in the index.html file....Was I not to copy the js file to assets/js folder?

Comment: that totally depends on your project structure. do you have angular in your package.json?

Comment: Under dependencies?

Comment: No it is not there

Comment: it has to be there

Comment: Do I have to install anything?